# Sending an ID with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

On my webpage I have this link:

```
<\a onclick="#" class="compose"></a>
```

By clicking the link, this script gets activated:

```
$(function(){
    $('.compose').click(function() { // Button which will activate our modal
        $('#popup_bestanden_edit_name').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal 
            animation: 'fade',  // fade, fadeAndPop, none
            animationspeed: 600,                // how fast animtions are
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,   // if you click background will modal close?
            dismissmodalclass: 'close'  // the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The script above will make this DIV visible, wich is a popup:

```
<div id="popup_bestanden_edit_name">
<div id="popupheading">
    Naam wijzigen
</div>

<div id="popupcontent">
    <p><form action="" method="post" name="naamwijzigen"><input name="naam" type="text"></form></p>

    <a href="#" class="popupbutton green close"><img src="<?php echo $domein.'/images/confirm_popup/tick.png'; ?>">Ja, wijzigen</a>

    <a href="#" class="popupbutton red close"><img src="<?php echo $domein.'/images/confirm_popup/cross.png'; ?>">Nee, annuleren</a>
</div>
```

The popup that opens gives people the opportunity to edit a name of a document on the website.
So when the link `<\a onclick="#" class="compose"></a>` is clicked, it has to send an id (`$fetch_row['id']`) to the popup, so I can use this in the further scripting.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery reveal plugin has many callback functions in which `opened` callback function that triggers 'after' the modal is opened.  See docs at [foundation.zurb.com](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/reveal.php)

```
echo "<a onclick='#' class='compose' id='".$fetch_row['id']."'></a>";

$(function(){
    $('.compose').click(function() { 

        var id = $(this).attr('id'); //getting id from clicked anchor tag

        $('#popup_bestanden_edit_name').reveal({ 
            animation: 'fade',  
            animationspeed: 600,               
            closeonbackgroundclick: true,   
            dismissmodalclass: 'close',//missing comma (,) added

            opened: function(id) { 
               $("#popup_bestanden_edit_name").append("<input type='hidden' name='myid' id='myid' value='"+id+"'>");
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Your id will set in `myid` element in popup get this from here.

Comment: This one i understand, but when i replace my script with yours and then click the link, the popup will not open anymore.

Comment: Update:

When i put OPENED above dismissModalClass, the popup appears, but i can't close it anymore by clicking the cancel button.
Then nothing happends.

Comment: There was a mistake, a comma was missing before opened. it iss corrected.

Comment: Hi Salim,

i added that one already, sorry, forgot to post it here.
That made everything work correctly except the Close button. dismissmodalclass does not make the div invisible after clicking the cancel button.

Comment: a js error makes not to work another , so I have to say another thing, writing mistake was in opened (oppened)

Comment: Oke, i changed that one, but still dismissmodalclass doesn't work.
The Cancel button does not hide the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Add the id to your a tag like this

```
<a onclick="#" class="compose" data-id="<?php echo $fetch_row['id']?>"></a>
```

Then fetch the id and send it to your popup with Jquery:

```
id = $(this).attr("data-id");
```

Now use this id wherever you want.

Comment: Well, i need to admit i'm not that good with jquery.
How do i use the id combined with PHP if i do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

add id to the anchor tag only i.e

```
<a id = '2' class='compose' ></a>
```

then you can get it like jQuery('.compose').attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

now everything is working i have one more question.
This is the code i use now:

```
echo "<a onclick='#' class='compose' id='".$fetch_row['id']."'></a>";

$(function(){
$('.compose').click(function() { 

    var id = $(this).attr('id'); //getting id from clicked anchor tag

    $('#popup_bestanden_edit_name').reveal({ 
        animation: 'fade',  
        animationspeed: 600,               
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,   
        dismissmodalclass: 'close',//missing comma (,) added

        opened: function(id) { 
           $("#popup_bestanden_edit_name").append("<input type='hidden' name='myid' id='myid' value='"+id+"'>");
        }

    });
    return false;
});
});
```

But when the link is clicked while people are on the bottom of the page, the popup will open on the top of the page.
But people need to scroll back to the top to see this.

How can i automatically send the user back to the top where the popup is being showed?